# Best way to switch controller and view of a route based on a property of model

Tags: ember.js

I need to change the view and controller of a route based on a property of a model. So for example lets assume I have a route hierarchy defined as:

```
Ember.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource("games", function () {
        this.resource('game', {path: ':game_id'}, function () {
            this.route('basics');
            this.route('advanced');            
        });
    });
});
```

And my game model looks like this:

```
App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    category: DS.attr('string)
});
```

So if the name of the game was football, and I wanted to go to basics route of that game then I would want to use footballBasicsController and use football-basics-view. The way I am doing this is by using the renderTemplate hook in the GameBasicsRoute like this:

```
AS.GameBasicsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    ......

    renderTemplate: function (controller, model) {
        var gameName = model.get("name"),
            template = gameName + "-basics",
            gameBasedController = controller;

        //if cannot resolve the template then use the default template
        template = (this.container.resolve('template:' + template)) ? template : 'game.basics';

        /**
         * first check if we have controller defined, if it is use the controller instance that is alive
         * or else create a new one
         * */
        if (this.container.lookupFactory('controller:' + gameName + "-basics")) {
            gameBasedController = this.controllerFor(gameName + '-basics');
            gameBasedController.set("model", model);
            controller.set('gameBasedController', typeBasedController);//might want to do sth with it later
        }

        this.render(template, {
            'controller': gameBasedController
        });

    },

});
```

This works well, but I am having bit of a issue in case where I want to leverage the didInsertElement hooks of view. Also the controllers are not completely destroyed(although it might be by design) - the reason I believe so is because the state of the properties are retained when I switch from one route to another.

I could have had just one GameBasicsView that switches templates based on the model property but then I am not sure how to set context controller to the view other than the default GameBasicsController.

Your feedback will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the game types so drastically different that they all need their own controllers and views? I would personally break things down at the template level and not at the controller level. Have a partial template wrapped in its own view for each game type, and they can all share the same controller...

That said, you could use the `render` helper, which will generate a controller for each partial template you include. You need to pass in the model context, but that is simple enough.

http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper

So in your case, you could do a number of things:

```
{{#if isFootball}}
  {{render "football" this}}
{{/if}}

{{#if isSoccer}}
  {{render "soccer" this}}
{{/if}}
```

`isFootball` could be a computed property that checks the game type and returns a boolean. That would generate `App.FootballView` and `App.FootballController` so you could then specify the behavior within those contexts.

Or, even better in your template you could bind the game type (category?) or you could compute a formatted string property:

```
{{render getGameTemplate this}}
```

And your games controller:

```
getGameTemplate: function () {
  return this.get('category') + "_formatted"; //You could format this template name string if needed
}.property('category')
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Matthew, for some reason i always thought that when using render helper, it will use the controller associated with the route where it is used. I'll definitely give this a try. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for the super late response but turns out render cannot take dynamic context name, would have been sweet if ember could allow for dynamic context names.